# How the spatial extent of a superpixel is a region of size S*S?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, superpixels

I am reading this paper [Achanta-SLIC Superpixel segmentation](http://www.kev-smith.com/papers/SLIC_Superpixels.pdf) where it says that the every superpixel cluster center is located at a distance of `S = root(N/k)` and that expected spatial extent of a superpixel is a region of `S * S` and the search for similar pixels is done in a spatial region of `2S*2S`.

Can someone please explain me this point as I am stuck at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the paper:

> Our algorithm takes as input a desired number of approximately equally-sized
>   superpixels K.

So, let's assume that our SP are approximately squares. You will have `K` of them.

> For an image with N pixels, the approximate size of each superpixel
>   is therefore N/K pixels

If you divide the image area `N` in `K` SP, every SP has (almost) `N/K` pixels. I.e., the area of each SP is `N/K`.

> For roughly equally sized superpixels there would be a superpixel center at every grid interval S = sqrt(N/K).

Each SP is assumed to be squared, with area `N/K`. The side of the square will then be `sqrt(area) = sqrt(N/K) = S`. This means that a SP center is `S` far from neighbours's centers.

> Since the spatial extent of any superpixel is approximately S^2 (the approximate area of a superpixel)

Well, the side of each square is `S`, then its area is `S^2` (which is the same as `N/K = sqrt(N/K)^2 = S^2`).

> we can safely assume that pixels that are associated with this cluster
>   center lie within a 2S × 2S area around the superpixel center

We mentioned that each side of the square will be `S`, then each pixels of the SP will lie within the size of half the diagonal from the center `sqrt(S/2)`, which is less than the side `sqrt(S/2) < S`. But SP are not exactly squares, so we want to be a little more flexible, and say that all pixels lie within the double of this distance: `2S`.

Comment: Thanks @Miki for the explanation :)

Comment: Could you please explain the last paragraph, still not clear @Miki ?